# selectize js breaking options and repeating input

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, selectize.js

**Hey **

I'm facing an issue with selectize on a dropdown.
Whenever I click in any options from the dropdown everything is fine...
However when i put any text input on the field, the options get weird...looks like it's repeating the text input i enter.
Tried to remove the highlight function but no result.

Scenario:

Using last version of Selectize on wordpress child theme.

Using selectize.js and selectize.min.js from dist/js/standalone.

Using an included script that is working on the child folders.

**script.js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#search').selectize({highlight: false})
});
```

**select list**

```
<div class="exampleSearch">
    <select  placeholder="Choose some technologies..." id="search" multiple="multiple">
       <option value="1">Sample Value 1</option>
       <option value="2">Sample Value 2</option>
       <option value="3">Sample Value 3</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn n-btn-flat">
</div>
```

**Some pictures to illustrate:**

[Before text input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmX16.png)

[after text input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iJy0.png)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you have some styles which are overriding default style for `selectize` and causing this issue.

Take a look at working example below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search').selectize({
    highlight: true
  })
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/css/selectize.default.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/selectize.js/0.12.6/js/standalone/selectize.min.js"></script>
<div class="exampleSearch">
  <select placeholder="Choose some technologies..." id="search" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">Sample Value 1</option>
    <option value="2">Sample Value 2</option>
    <option value="3">Sample Value 3</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn n-btn-flat">
</div>
```

Comment: Tried to remove all my childtheme includes , the local selectize and css and loading all from <script> tags like you posted here... Same result...
Looked on my additional css for any override and nothing is overriding...

But the parent theme maybe it's overriding? tried to find in all files in the parent theme for any selectize related word and nothing pops....

One thing I noticed is when I text input on the dropdown box, on the page source code, it creates two "span" instead of one, so the option gets broken into 2 spans... Not sure if suppose

Comment: @AndréGarcia it is supposed to do that to highlight matching text in some spans and keep another spans to highlight not matched items.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue and ended up solving it (thanks to the comment about how span elements are being added on text input) by noticing that I had some custom styles that were causing the issue. The offending CSS was:

```
span {
  display: block;
}
```

Which I replaced with:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```